# Apache Server Security (HSTS, Sniffing, Clickjack, XSS) not working

Tags: apache, server, header, xss, sniffing

I am not into configuring servers when it comes to security. I try to secure my website as much as possible. Found some snippets and made my custom .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=360000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>
```

When using tools like Checkbot SEO it tells me that I don`t use HSTS, clickjack and XSS protection.

Some content though is sniffing protected. But only like 13%.

Is the .htaccess file correct? I am using all-inkl as a hoster. As much I know all-inkl sends headers. I also tried to put all rules together like:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=360000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>
```